# how to connect to different apis on different button click

Tags: android, api

[image: this is the home ui which is displayed using home fragment]

**I have placed buttons on these 6 items now all I need is when a user clicks on a button it has to connect to a api fetch and display content ,similarly clicking on all other buttons should connect to respective api s.Now creating a new activity and new adapter for each is causing redundant code how to implement this properly please help me**

**home fragment**

```
class Homefragment : Fragment() {

 lateinit var buttondept:Button


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homefragment, container, false)
       buttondept=view.findViewById(R.id.btnDept)
       buttondept.setOnClickListener {
           val intent=Intent(context,descactivity::class.java)
           intent.putExtra("option","department")
           startActivity(intent)
       }

    return view



}
```

}

**desc activity**

```
class descactivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var recyclerDashBoard: RecyclerView
lateinit var layoutmanager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

lateinit var recyclerAdapter:Horizontal_RecyclerView
lateinit var progressLayout: RelativeLayout
lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
lateinit var button: Button
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_descactivity)
    val bookInfoList = arrayListOf<Book>()
    recyclerDashBoard = findViewById(R.id.recyclerDashboard)

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar)


    progressLayout = findViewById(R.id.progresslayout)
    progressLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE

         val intent=getIntent()
         val selectionOption= intent.getStringExtra("option")
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this as Context)
        val url = "http://13.235.250.119/v1/book/fetch_books/"

        if (ConnectionManager().checkConnectivity(this as Context)) {
            val jsonObjectRequest =
                object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null, Response.Listener {
                    try {
                        progressLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                        val success = it.getBoolean("success")
                        if (success) {
                            val data = it.getJSONArray("data")
                            for (i in 0 until data.length()) {
                                val bookJSONObject = data.getJSONObject(i)
                                val bookobject = Book(
                                    bookJSONObject.getString("book_id"),
                                    bookJSONObject.getString("name"),
                                    bookJSONObject.getString("author"),
                                    bookJSONObject.getString("rating"),
                                    bookJSONObject.getString("price"),
                                    bookJSONObject.getString("image")

                                )
                                bookInfoList.add(bookobject)
                                layoutmanager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                                recyclerAdapter =
                                    Horizontal_RecyclerView(this as Context, bookInfoList)
                                recyclerDashBoard.adapter = recyclerAdapter
                                recyclerDashBoard.layoutManager = layoutmanager


                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this as Context,
                                "some error occurred!!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this as Context,
                            "some unknown error occured!!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }


                }, Response.ErrorListener {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this as Context,
                        "volley error occured!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()

                }) {
                    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                        headers["content-type"] = "application/json"
                        headers["token"] = "a07daa7f3efb3b"
                        return headers
                    }
                }


            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the next screen to be displayed is same for all options and the API request/response is also similar then you can pass the option clicked in a bundle with intent. And based on that you can call different API and handle the UI there.

Comment: @krrishnaaaa next screen will be same ,but apis will be different but response will be similar ,can u share me a code example please

Comment: well i don't want to be rude.. but you share your progress and I can suggest the modification required. Meanwhile you can make the changes like intent.putExtra("option", "department"); startActivity(intent); and in next activity you can get the extra option Intent intent = getIntent(); String selectionOption = intent.getStringExtra("option");

Comment: @Krrishnaaaa sir check now i have made some changes

Comment: you passed the option to `descactivity` but you are not using it. You should put some if else condition to change the URL. And more important thing is to learn some architecture and use that instead of writing everything in the Activity itself. For now i will suggest you to create separate methods for all api calls and based on the "option" passed from previous screen call respective method.